# Selenium hanging with xvfb

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb

I am attempting to run automated selenium headless tests, and I'm running into the issue where the tests hang for some inexplicable reason. The full snippet is on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/CqrbGa4D), but the relevant portion of the code is reproduced below:

```
# stress testing
i = 0
while True:
  print i
  d = webdriver.Remote(
      service.service_url,
      desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
  )
  print i, "started driver"
  d.get("http://www.facebook.com")
  print i, "got fb"
  d.quit()
  print i, "quit"
  i += 1
```

Sample output is

```
0
0 started driver
0 got fb
0 quit
...
11 <hang>
```

Which indicates that `webdriver.Remote` is refusing to properly initiate the driver. This also occurs when the driver instance is constructed directly with `webdriver.Chrome` (instead of running the ChromeDriver as a service).

After sending SIGINT to the hanging program, I get a stacktrace ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Fc4xQYJc)) indicating a blocking socket read somewhere in the constructor.

ChromeDriver's log ([dropcanvas](http://dropcanvas.com/batxi)) doesn't seem to indicate anything amiss, and I'm quite puzzled as to what is happening here.

Similar questions have been asked previously, the most relevant being [Selenium Chromedriver Hangs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463934/selenium-chromedriver-hangs); however, I cannot reproduce the accepted solution (starting Xvfb anew for each instantiation of `webdriver...`). Here, the equivalent would be calling `Xvfb.start` immediately preceding `d = webdriver.Remote...` and calling `Xvfb.stop` at the end of the loop; I have tried this to no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: As indicated by the stacktrace, `webdriver.Remote` was hanging on some socket read function; I traced the request to be

```
POST 'http://127.0.0.1:<chromedriver_port>/session'
```

with body

```
 '{"desiredCapabilities": {"platform": "ANY", "browserName": "chrome", "version": "", "javascriptEnabled": true}}'
```

So it seems like ChromeDriver isn't responding for some reason. Will continue debugging.